How can i use GLSL shaders with raylib-rust?
Right now i'm trying to use a simple shader in my raylib app.
This is my simple_shader.fs file
#version 330

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}

This is my main.rs file
use raylib::consts::ConfigFlags::FLAG_VSYNC_HINT;
use raylib::ffi::{GetScreenWidth, SetConfigFlags};
use raylib::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    const WINDOW_W: i32 = 800;
    const WINDOW_H: i32 = 600;

    unsafe {
        let (mut rl, rt) = raylib::init()
            .size(WINDOW_W, WINDOW_H)
            .title("raylib [core] example!")
            .build();

        let shader: Shader = rl.load_shader(&rt, None, Some("simple_shader.fs")).unwrap();

        while !rl.window_should_close() {
            let mut d: RaylibDrawHandle = rl.begin_drawing(&rt);

            d.clear_background(Color::BLACK);

            let _ = d.begin_shader_mode(&shader);
            d.draw_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, Color::WHITE);
        }
    }
}

The shader is supposed to color the rectangle from white to blue but nothing happens.
My window shows, the shader loads and unloads successfully but its still just showing a white square on a black background.
Thanks in advance.

I don't know about raylib; do you need to set-up a camera, or does it automatically use the screen co-ordinates?
